# Creating a digital Clock Class using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am learning a new JVM language; Kotlin and I am attempting to create a ***digital clock*** class containing the ***Hour*** and ***Minute*** attributes with the ***sethour***, ***setminute*** and ***view*** methods describing behaviour.

***THIS is the code :***

```
class clock (Hour: Int, Minute: Int)  {


}
```

I am not sure how I would design the methods, if someone could assist me I would really appreciate that.

***Cheers, 
Andre***

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, particularly the meaning of `view` method. Could you write down at least the method signatures?

Comment: @voddan In this case the view should probably be _**show**_ . The type would be void, and the methods would be public. So the clock would set the hour, set the minute and show the time to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need explicitly declare setters and getters in Kotlin. You can use something like that:

```
class Clock(var hour: Int, var minute: Int) {
    fun show() = println("$hour:$minute")
}
```

Or if you don't want to set `hour` and `minute` in constructor:

```
class Clock() {
    var hour = 0
    var minute = 0

    fun show() = println("$hour:$minute")
}
```

For more information see this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Clock(var minute: Int, var hour: Int) {
  fun show() = println("hour : $hour, minute : $minute")
}
```

or

```
data class Clock(var minute: Int = 0, var hour: Int = 12) {
  fun show() = println("hour : $hour, minute : $minute")
}
```

if use 'data class' you don't create getter, setter

http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html